# Find two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that matrix $AB$ that is invertible but $BA$ is not.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to find two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that matrix $AB$ that is invertible but $BA$ is not.

Have you got any ideas of easy examples?
Thank you!

Comment: As has been suggested in Hagen's answer, square matrices aren't going to get you there. I suggest you think in terms of linear mappings between two spaces, one larger than the other. It's easy to map from a small space to a larger space and back to the smaller space without losing information, but what about the other way around?

Comment: For square matrices, use determinants to see that we cannot do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&a'\end{bmatrix}$, $B=\begin{bmatrix}b\\b'\end{bmatrix}$. Choose $a, a',b,b'$ such that $ab+a'b'\neq 0$. Then $AB=\begin{bmatrix}ab+a'b'\end{bmatrix}$ is invertible, but
$$\det(BA)=\det\biggl(\begin{bmatrix}ab&a'b\\ab'&a'b'\end{bmatrix}\biggr)=0.$$

Answer (score 7):

*Hint:* Nobody said that $A,B$ be square matrices.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to include that both $AB$ and $BA$ have to be defined.

Comment: Hint: if A is m by n, and B is n by m. then both AB and BA are defined.